# Use Properties of baseclass in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, inheritance, reference, radix

I have a class "ManagerClass" which is inherited from a baseClass "Base".
The BaseClass is not in the same assembly, there is a reference to the BaseClass Assembly.

If I set a reference to the "ManagerClass" Assembly from a third Assembly I was expecting to get access to the "ManagerClass" and the Properties of the BaseClass.
But I get an error, that there is no reference to the BaseClass.

Could this work as I wished or isn't it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to the Assembly the base class is in your third assembly??

Comment: Gaining access to BaseClass properties depends on their declaration. If they are Private, then no it isn't possible. Public - yes you can. Protected - you will have to write a new method to access the Protected properties

Comment: To add a reference from the third class to the base class is exactly what I want to avoid. Isn't it possible without reference? With a reference every thing works.